# Unpack a nested list

Tags: python, list

My question is simple.
There are two lists.
The first is a list of integers:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

The other is a list of lists:

```
b = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
```

How could I get the result below:

```
result = [[1, 'a', 'b'], [2, 'c', 'd'], [3, 'e', 'f']]
```

Thanks.

Comment: You `b` looks invalid. Please format it correctly if it is a list of lists of strings.

Comment: Is b really containing a reference to itself? Good luck unpacking that!

Comment: @gnibbler: try this: `a = range(6); a[1] = a; print a`

Comment: @JoelCornett, yep it detects loops and cleverly replaces them with `...` but that's not the same as unrolling the list

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
>>> [[aa] + bb for aa, bb in zip(a, b)]
[[1, 'a', 'b'], [2, 'c', 'd'], [3, 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: `[1,a,b]` is a list of an integer and two … what? What are `a` and `b`?

Comment: @sgzhan This examples works for strings and it will also work for other data types like whatever you just mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

In Python3

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
>>> [aa+bb for *aa, bb in zip(a,b)]
[[1, 'a', 'b'], [2, 'c', 'd'], [3, 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: +1 Interesting although this method couldn't be used if there were 3 lists like `a = [1, 2, 3]` `b = [6, 7, 8]` `c = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]` since only one starred expression can be used.

Comment: @jamylak, no -- this works perfectly well on `a`, `b`, `c` as you define them. One starred expression is all that's needed.

Comment: @senderle `>>> [aa+bb+cc for *aa, bb, cc in zip(a,b,c)]
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list` `>>> [aa+bb+cc for *aa, *bb, cc in zip(a,b,c)]
SyntaxError: two starred expressions in assignment`

Comment: @jamylak, `>>> [aa+cc for *aa, cc in zip(a, b, c)]` -> `[[1, 6, 'a', 'b'], [2, 7, 'c', 'd'], [3, 8, 'e', 'f']]`.

Comment: @senderle right, my bad, I didn't think of it that way, thanks :D

Comment: @jamylak, well, as I know all too well, extended unpacking can be counterintuitive at times!

Answer (score 0):

The following Python code will unpack each list and assemble it in the form you indicated.

```
[[a[i]] + b[i]  for i in range(min(len(a),len(b)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be:

```
index = 0
l = b
for i in a:
    l[index].append(i)
    index += 1
```

Comment: This will `append` the items to the right (wrong side)... note that `insert(0, x)` is an O(N) operation if you chose to use that. You could use a `deque` to make it O(1) but that might be going too far when you can just use a list comp.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python's `enumerate` function you can loop over a list with an index. Using `x.extend(y)` will prepend the values in list `x` to list `y`.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]

result = []
for index, value in enumerate(a):
    aa = [value]
    aa.extend(b[index])
    result.append(aa)
```